# Error Handling in Web Api Self Hosted Server for ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

I have a project running ASP.Net WebApi in a self hosted configuration and I am using an `ActionFilterAttribute` class as a filter for some security checks and an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` as the exception handling class.

When I raise an exception in my `ApiController` of type `HttpResponseException` it is being ignored by the `ExceptionFilterAttribute` class as expected.

**The issue is** that when i raise an exception of type `HttpResponseException` in the security filter of type `ActionFilterAttribute` it **is** being caught by the `ExceptionFilterAttribute` class.

When debugging I have found that that exception is being changed to

> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
>   the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
>   exception for details.

What can I do to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior seems like a bug. Could you share how your action filter looks like? 
By the way, setting the action filter actioncontext's Response property to the Http response would short-circuit the pipeline and wondering if you can avoid throwing HttpResponseException from the action filter.

Comment: `public class SecureApiAccessFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        { if(cookie_expired(actionContext.Request)){return throw new HttpResponseException(requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,"Session timed out"));}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply it worked like a charm i replaced the throw with `actionContext.Response=requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,"Session timed out");`